# Convert The 12-Character to Long

Tags: java, android, emv

Authorised amount of the transaction. Format is "n 12" and length is 6 bytes for example a value of **1234567** is stored as Hex  **00 00 01 23 45 67**.

```
TLV > 9F02 06 000001234567
```

**Q**: How to convert **000001234567** to **1234567** ?

I tried like follows but it doesn't work:

```
public static long byteArrayToLong(@NonNull byte[] from, int offset, @NonNull EEndian endian) {
    try {
        byte[] fromFixed = new byte[8];
        if(from.length < 8) {
            System.arraycopy(from, 0, fromFixed, fromFixed.length-from.length, from.length);
        }
        else  {
            System.arraycopy(from, 0, fromFixed, 0, fromFixed.length);
        }
        if (endian == EEndian.BIG_ENDIAN) {
            return ((fromFixed[offset] << 24) & 0xff00000000000000L) | ((fromFixed[offset + 1] << 16) & 0xff000000000000L)
                    | ((fromFixed[offset + 2] << 8) & 0xff0000000000L) | ((fromFixed[offset + 3]) & 0xff00000000L)
                    | ((fromFixed[offset + 4] << 24) & 0xff000000) | ((fromFixed[offset + 5] << 16) & 0xff0000)
                    | ((fromFixed[offset + 6] << 8) & 0xff00) | (fromFixed[offset + 7] & 0xff);
        } else {
            return ((fromFixed[offset + 7] << 24) & 0xff00000000000000L) | ((fromFixed[offset + 6] << 16) & 0xff000000000000L)
                    | ((fromFixed[offset + 5] << 8) & 0xff0000000000L) | ((fromFixed[offset + 4]) & 0xff00000000L)
                    | ((fromFixed[offset + 3] << 24) & 0xff000000) | ((fromFixed[offset + 2] << 16) & 0xff0000)
                    | ((fromFixed[offset + 1] << 8) & 0xff00) | (fromFixed[offset] & 0xff);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

// calling above code

```
byte[] amountAuthorisedNumeric = transLogResponse.getAmountAuthorisedNumeric(i); // new byte[] {(byte)00x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x23, (byte)0x45, (byte)0x67}
Log.i(TAG, "AMOUNT1 is " + byteArrayToHexString(amountAuthorisedNumeric));       // 000001234567

amount = byteArrayToLong(amountAuthorisedNumeric, 0, BIG_ENDIAN); // error in here
Log.i(TAG, "AMOUNT2 is " + amount);                               // 19088743 (result expected is 1234567, not 19088743)
```

Comment: Could you use BigInteger?

Comment: You are intepreting hex as a `long`, which indeeds converts to `19088743`. (`19088743` is a decimal representation of  `1234567` in hex).

Comment: I tried new BigInteger("000001234567", 16).toString(), the result is 19088743

Comment: @Giovanni, correct. Thanks. I change radix from 16 to 10, its worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I suggest using [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String value = "000001234567";
        BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(value);
        System.out.println(bigInteger.longValue());
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ JavaTestingGround ---
1234567
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
```

**The other route is using [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) to parse the value.**

```
/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String value = "000001234567";

        System.out.println(Long.parseLong(value));
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
1234567
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
```

Comment: Even if every digit were a 9, that is small enough to easily fit within a long.

Comment: I agree. Updating answer.